# Fragment Implementing LocationListener causes build error on requestLocationUpdates, is my understanding of interfaces incorrect?

Tags: android, inheritance, android-fragments, interface, polymorphism

I have followed the steps [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#save-state) and in my **fragment**, I implement `LocationListener`, and then request location updates by calling:

`LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,locationRequest, this);`

But it gives the error saying Cannot resolve method due to the last parameter (this) being a fragment rather than a LocationListener.

How can this be the case, given that I have implemented LocationListener? Should my fragment class not now be of type LocationListener? Must I cast `this` to a LocationListener object?

Another way I could do this is by creating an instance of the LocationListener in the fragment, such as:

```
locationListener = new LocationListener(){
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            currentLocation = location;
            if(teeLocation != null && currentLocation != null){
                currentDistance = UtilityFacade.getDistance(currentLocation, teeLocation);
                distanceText.setText("Current dist: "+currentDistance +" yards");
                accuracyText.setText("Accuracy: " +UtilityFacade.metresToYards(currentLocation.getAccuracy()) +" yards");
            } else {
                distanceText.setText("Ready.");
                accuracyText.setText("Accuracy: " +UtilityFacade.metresToYards(currentLocation.getAccuracy()) +" yards");
            }
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    };
```

How is it possible to create an instance of LocationListener if it is an interface? Can you still create instances but you must declare the methods inside the object instantiation? I thought the interface had to be implemented?

**EDIT** 
Upon casting `this` to a LocationListener as below,

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,locationRequest, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
```

at runtime I get an error:
`Cannot cast 'com....Fragment to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener'`

Comment: There are 2 different `LocationListener`'s make sure you implemented the right one

Comment: Yeah, try importing `android.location.LocationListener` instead.

Comment: @aindurti no he needs to implement `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` since he is using the fused location API